# how to delay after creating record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-models

Basically i need to create an association right after_save: :create ward

**Location.rb**

```
 after_save :createward      

  def createward
    w = Ward.find_by_name(self.city)
    if w.nil?
      c = self.create_ward({:name => self.city})
      self.ward_id = c.id  #this line should be delayed because - c.id is called to soon. 
    else
      self.ward_id = w.id
    end
  end
```

This sort of works, most of the time it will create or associate records but, sometimes c.id will be  nil because self.ward_id = c.id line is executed before new ward is created, thus self.ward_id is usually nil ;/ 
Any ideas how to solve this one would be helpful :)

Comment: c.id being nil is probably more indicative of your create failing than anything else.  Do you have validations or anything that would cause create_ward to fail?  I'm assuming ward is a has_one relationship

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if you provided the code that connects `Ward` and `Location` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a delay... it doesn't work that way. After the `create` you'll have your record already. It's more likely that the record isn't saving sometimes. You can use `.create_ward!` (with an `!`) to raise an error if save fails. From the API docs:

> create_association!(attributes = {})
>
> Does the same as create_association, but raises ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid if the record is invalid.

Of course you'd then need to trap the exception... Or not. Either way at least this way you're stating your expectations (and enforcing them with an Exception).

Comment: Cool, thanks for reminding me about the enforcing :)